# How to send email through server alias mail

Tags: php, email, server

I've create a script that used the ipn of PayPal. All working perfectly, after the purchasing the data of the clients are inserted in the database. But recently the server of my hosting provider doesn't send the email. I don't understand the reason. I'm trying so to create an alias email server for send the email of contact form through the alias mail and it's working!
Now i want replicate the license send with alias mail server, actually i send the email with this code:

```
*$headers = 'From: '.$AdminEmail . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$AdminEmail . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)*
```

In the past this code working good but now doesn't working more. How can send the email through the alias server mail?

Comment: If it was working before, iI think it would be worthwile to understand why it's not working anymore. Has the config changed? What do the logfiles say?

Comment: Do you mean by alias mail server a local MTA (like exim) that is configured to use a relay mail server? that should work, I actually did that many times to avoid setting up my own mailserver (which is sometimes not even possible in a reliable way ,e.g. if you are behind a dialup line...)

Comment: I tried to contact support but being free hosting does not give much explanation. What should I include in the log file? I can try to simulate a purchase request to PayPal via the sandbox.

Comment: Well, testing the sendmail functionality does not require the involvement of Paypal I think :)

Comment: Yeah but the problem appears when the client buy the license, it isn't sended at the client. But with the canged that I've apported in the contact form, using the alias mail server, the mail working good.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your last sentence - so is it working now? That would make the whole question obsolete.
My point above was that you should investigate the send mail functionality isolated first an then integrate taht with your paypal / purchasing functionality to make sure you don't try to solve many problems with one step (which usually doesn't work out that well...)

Comment: The sending of the email only works if I use the mail alias that comes from space hosting.
This email alias currently I used to send emails from the support form on the site.
I would like to replicate the operation in the code I posted above, in particular, I would try to send emails directly with the alias email.

Comment: Ah, so you try to change the "From" and then the email is not send anymore. This is probably a security setting from your hostingprovider to protect themselves from being misused by spammers.

Comment: So how can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outcome of the discussion in the comments is that your provider restricts you from changing the from: field for email sent from you php scripts.

As a result of this, you need to use a external mail server that allows you to do so or talk to your provider if they can provide another (probably paid) solution.

Comment: You can learn about the cause of adding some kind of exception in the code I pasted above?
That way I'll know the exact reason.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. IMHO you would need access to both php/webserver log and mail server logfiles.